# search options based on data

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, solr, search-engine

I write an example to be more practive.
I need to know if it is possible to next search based on the data I have in my database, fulltextsearch engines in sqlserver-2008 or Apache Solr:

Case 1:

Data in the database:

```
Myriam
Miriam
Myrian
Miriam
...
```

Query:

```
Myria
```

Results that I want to return:

```
Myriam
Miriam
Myrian
Miriam
```

Case 2:

Data in the database:

```
Roberto Gonzalez
Roberto Perez
...
```

Query:

```
Robeto
```

Results that I want to return:

```
Roberto Bonzalez
Roberto Perez
```

I want to know if is possible to search in both engines and decide which of these work

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use text field type in Solr it will automaticly retrive results 'Myriam' or "Miriam" etc. 
If you use this field type in your solr schema it will tokenize your text and retrieve "roberto XXX" for "reberto" query

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```